# Changing NA_character value in matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, na

I have in the 7th row the value `NA_character` I want to change to `"e"`.
I tried:

```
a[a == "NA_character_"]  = "e"
a[a == "NA"]  = "e"
a[a == NA]  = "e"
a[a == NA_character_]  = "e"
```

with no success.

```
> dput(head(a, 10))
structure(list("e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", 
    "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", NA_character_, "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", 
    "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", 
    "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", 
    "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", 
    "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", 
    "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", 
    "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
    "e", "p", "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", 
    "p", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "p", "p", "e"), .Dim = c(10L, 
50L))
```

Comment: What is `NA_character_` ? From what I know, things in R that are missing are simply `NA`. Have you tried `a[is.na(a)] <- 'e'` ?

Comment: As noted above, the missing piece of information here is that you don't use `==` to identify NAs in R, you use `is.na()`.

Comment: It inserts NULL and not 'e'

Comment: @CoreyLevinson Check out `?NA` – it lists the several flavours of `NA` that are possible in R.

Comment: @Avi That's weird: Corey's code works fine for me.

Comment: Corey's recommendation is correct. `NA == NA` returns `NA`, not `TRUE`, because who knows if two missing values are equal to each other. Maybe they are, maybe they aren't. `is.na()` tells you whether or not something is `NA`.

Comment: And `NA` (or any of the more specific versions, `NA_character_`) should never be used with quotes. `"NA"` is a string containing the letters `"N"` and `"A"`. `NA` is a missing value.